# How to backup WhatsApp chats including voice notes

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

There are plenty of questions addressing WhatsApp backups but none seem to work for me.

Even trying the built in options isn't working at all. Using export chat without media only goes back to February and seems to top out at 40379 messages.

Exporting with media is even worse. It ignores almost every message and media file and only does the last 600 texts.

How on earth do I actually back up a complete chat?